# Looking for meta data which matches certain criteria and was created after a certain date

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, wordpress

I've got the below SQL statement which runs in MySQL on a WordPress installation. I'm looking for meta data that matches certain criteria and was created after a certain date.

However, WordPress doesn't store the date that metadata was added to posts, so I've created the metadata itself (wpcf-post-likes), the date it was added (wpcf-post-like-date) and a third piece of metadata which is created at the same time that contains the IDs of the previous two delimited by an exclamation mark (wpcf-post-like-date-link).

I then use the following SQL statement to get likes on posts written by the current author (example ID included in the SQL code below) after a certain date. It works, but it takes about 7 - 8 seconds to run, which is far from ideal. Is there a more efficient version of the same statement?

```
SELECT `meta_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE   `post_id` IN (
            SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_author = $user_id
        ) AND
        `meta_value` IN (

        SELECT CONCAT(combined_ids_a.`meta_id`, '!', combined_ids_b.`meta_id`) AS `combined_meta_id` FROM (

            SELECT `meta_id`, 'like_id' AS `meta_type` FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-likes'
            AND `meta_value` NOT LIKE '1837'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', 1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

            UNION

            SELECT  `meta_id`, 'like_date' AS `meta_type`  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date'
            AND `meta_value` > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', -1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

        ) AS combined_ids_a JOIN 

        (

            SELECT `meta_id`, 'like_id' AS `meta_type` FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-likes'
            AND `meta_value` NOT LIKE '1837'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', 1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

            UNION

            SELECT  `meta_id`, 'like_date' AS `meta_type`  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
            WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date'
            AND `meta_value` > '01-02-2016 09:20:34'
            AND `meta_id` IN 
            (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', -1) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC)

        ) AS combined_ids_b    

        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest staring with this:

```
AND `meta_id` IN 
        (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`meta_value`, '!', 1) 
         FROM `wp_postmeta` 
         WHERE `meta_key` 
         LIKE 'wpcf-post-like-date-link' 
         ORDER BY `meta_id` 
         DESC)
```

LIKE text searching, sorting with the ORDER, additional subquery on the same `wp_postmeta` table are sources of the lengthy query execution. [Rewriting subqueries as joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)